# Python2.7: Display log name AFTER log level in python logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

By default, python's logging framework prints the log name before the log level. For example,

```
2016-02-04 20:38:19,765 | common_operations.update_vip | INFO | ----- Function to update vip and validate updation -----
```

What I want to do is get my `log level` to appear before the `log name`. I want this --

```
2016-02-04 20:38:19,765 | INFO | common_operations.update_vip | ----- Function to update vip and validate updation -----
```

This is my code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("common_operations.update_vip")
logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
return logger
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: and the reason why you want that is because?

Comment: Looks better, mostly.